# Unable to download PDF in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to add pdf file download feature to a laravel 5.8 application. Found a fairly simply and straight forward package [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) and followed the documentation but when I call the uri to download the file, no file is downloaded. Tested on both chrome and firefox and got the error

> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Here's what I have done so far

1. `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`
2. Added `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,` to providers array in `config.app` and `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,` to the aliases array like this

```
'providers' => [

    /*
        * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
        */
    ...

    /*
        * Package Service Providers...
        */
    Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,
    Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,

    /*
        * Application Service Providers...
        */
    ...
],

'aliases' => [

    // others
    'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,

],
```

1. Then in my controller, I wrote the function to handle the pdf download like this

```
public function getReceipt(Order $order)
{
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('receipt');

    return $pdf->download('receipt.pdf');
}
```

4. And finally a route in `web.php` for the download `Route::get('orders/{order}/receipt', 'OrderController@getReceipt');`

Have I missed step in using this package? I would appreciate help from anyone familiar with this package.

Comment: @CHARITRASHRESTHA it does look so, let me do a quick test on a staging server

Answer (score 0):

You can simply increase the execution time period. By using 
`set_time_limit(300);` or Check your CSS maybe that's too complex or importing bulk modules.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that simply moving my code to a staging environment running apache and I was able to download. That simple.

Comment: close or accept the answer..